# excel - keep column reference fixed when using structured reference and dragging equation across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with 27 'restriction' columns and one 'total area' column as well as an identifier/name, and I am subtracting the total area from the restrictions to then give me the useable area in that zone.

my table is of the form:

identifier/total_area/restriction1/restriction2....restriction27

and will end up as:

identifier/total_area/restriction1/restriction2....restriction27/allowed_area1/allowed_area2...27

Basically, if you use a structured reference in the form:

```
=[@[area]]-[@restriction1]
```

then it behaves a lot like

```
=B2-C2
```

but it would be useful to have something that acts like this would:

```
=$B2-C2
```

so that the same 'total_area' column is being referenced each time.

Is there a way to keep the structured reference while being able to fix one of the columns?

At the moment it works fine with

```
=$B2-[@restriction1]
```

it would just be useful to know if there was a function in the future as structured references are cleaner than direct cell references

Comment: Welcome to SU. Not sure I understand what you are asking.  The [column specifier](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912#bmtable_names) refers to the entire column of that table (which you are specifying with `$A6`). So what is not working as you expect? Please [edit] your question to be more specific and give an example.

Comment: Near Duplicate of [Structured References: Absolute and Relative Addressing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511276/structured-references-absolute-and-relative-addressing).  Try:  `=Table1[@[Total_area]:[Total_area]]-[Restriction1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called a name manager. (Formulas Ribbon, or Alt-I-N-D using keyboard short cuts)

In the **name manger** you can give a name to a cell, a range or grouping of cells, plus more. If you "name" a Range `total_area`, then in your formula would be:  `=total_area - c2`

Using the Naming convention: copy / paste would update `c2` but `total_area` would remain a static range via Naming convention.

Comment: ah good idea, i hadn't thought of using named ranges